# How to include directories with Terragrunt

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

Is there a way to copy directories into the Terragrunt workspace?

I've come across the `include_in_copy` attritube, and I've tried something like this

```
  terraform {
  
  source = "git@gitlab.foo"

  include_in_copy = [
    "${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/foo-dir/"
  ]

}
```

But, it looks like this only copies content from whatever the source location is

However, in my case, I want to copy in an entire directory that's in the absolute path to the first terragrunt.hcl file, hence the use of the `get_parent_terragrunt_dir()` function.

This is what my file structure looks like.

```
├── deploy
│   └── bar
│       └── terragrunt.hcl
├── foo-dir
└── terragrunt.hcl
```

I'm calling terragrunt from inside the `deploy/bar` directory and I would like to include the `foo-dir` directory as well, but it looks like I'm doing something wrong.

Is there a function that might be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `include_in_copy` will not work for this. Looking at the source code, it first generates a list of files in the source directory, then filters it based on the files matching the `include_in_copy` patterns. Hence, it can never match something outside of the source directory.

Instead, you might try to copy using a hook:

```
terraform {
  after_hook "copy-modules" {
    commands = ["terragrunt-read-config"]
    execute  = ["rsync", "-avq", "${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/foo-dir/", "${get_working_dir()}/foo-dir/"]
  }
}
```